# Copy directory & subdirectory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have a folder structure something like this,

```
Folder 1  
     Folder 11 
       Folder 111 
       ... Some files .... 
     Folder 12 
       Folder 121 
       ... Some files .... 
     Folder 13 
     .... Some Files ... 

Folder 2
```

Now programatically i have to copy entire Folder1 to Folder 2

i tried following,

```
bool success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:Folder1Path toPath:Folder2Path error:nil];
```

but its creating only Folder1 inside folder2 ,

Is there no way to copy subdirectory recursively